# I can not connect to my php web service using the android emulator

Tags: java, php, android

I have a web services programmed in PHP and I want to connect to it from the android emulator to verify my cellphone number whit account kit facebook. Up until this point everything works fine but when I have to leave the other activity to register my data set it stays in the waiting dialogue

I thought it could be the

> alertdialog.dismiss

the problem but I'm not sure

My BASE_URL is: 10.0.2.2:80/godrink/

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
Button btn_continue;

IGoDrinkAPI mService;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mService = Common.getAPI();



    btn_continue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);

    btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Loguearemos con el telefono de celular / movil. > Abrira a la pagina de facebook
            startLoginPage(LoginType.PHONE);

        }
    });



}

private void startLoginPage(LoginType loginType) {

    //Estamos pasando con un intent a la activity donde esta para registrarse
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountKitActivity.class);
    AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder builder =
            new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(loginType,AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN);

    intent.putExtra(AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,builder.build());
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        AccountKitLoginResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(AccountKitLoginResult.RESULT_KEY);

        if (result.getError() != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel"+result.getError().getErrorType().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            if(result.getAccessToken() != null){
                final android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please waiting");


                //Get User phone and Check exists on server

                AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final Account account) {

                        mService.checkUserExists(account.getPhoneNumber().toString())
                                .enqueue(new Callback<CheckUserResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<CheckUserResponse> call, Response<CheckUserResponse> response) {

                                        CheckUserResponse userResponse = response.body();
                                        if(userResponse.isExists()){

                                            //If User already exists, just strat new Activity
                                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            //Else, need register
                                            alertDialog.dismiss();

                                            showRegisterDialog(account.getPhoneNumber().toString());

                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<CheckUserResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                                    }
                                });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {

                        Log.d("ERROR",accountKitError.getErrorType().getMessage());

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

private void showRegisterDialog(final String phone) {

   final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
   alertDialog.setTitle("REGISTER");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View register_layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_layout,null);

    final MaterialEditText edt_name = (MaterialEditText)register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
    final MaterialEditText edt_address = (MaterialEditText)register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edt_address);
    final MaterialEditText edt_birthdate = (MaterialEditText)register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edt_birthdate);

    Button btn_register = (Button)register_layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

    edt_birthdate.addTextChangedListener(new PatternedTextWatcher("####-##-##"));

    //Event

    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Close dialog
            alertDialog.create().dismiss();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_address.getText().toString())) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter your Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_birthdate.getText().toString())) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter your Birthdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_name.getText().toString())) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }

            final android.app.AlertDialog watingDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
            watingDialog.show();
            watingDialog.setMessage("Please waiting");

            mService.registerNewUser(phone,
                    edt_name.getText().toString(),
                    edt_birthdate.getText().toString(),
                    edt_address.getText().toString())
                    .enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                            watingDialog.dismiss();
                            User user = response.body();

                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getError_msg())) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User register Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                //Start New Activity

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

                            watingDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });


        }


    });

    alertDialog.setView(register_layout);
    alertDialog.show();



}

//Generaremos una KEY para nuestra Aplicacion
private void printKeyHash() {

    try{
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.rebcesp.godrink",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature:info.signatures){

            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KEYHASH", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT));

        }

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: probably your emulator does not have access to your server. Check if it has first

Answer (score 0):

You can only create alerDialog.create()  or alertDialog.dismiss()

you can not like this : alertDialog.create().dismiss();